# Determining bounds for a sum with nested infinite series

Tags: functions, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, exponential-function, computational-complexity

I am computing the inner product of the characters of the trivial  and the $k$-th irreducible two dimensional representations of the dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2 n$ when $n$ is even. The derivation is as follows.

\begin{align}
\langle \chi_{\sigma_k}, \chi_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} \rangle_{D_n} &= \frac{1}{2 n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0} 2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k l}{n}\right)
\nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{ n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0}  \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k l}{n}\right)
\nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{ n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0} \left(\sum^\infty_{m = 0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^m \left(\frac{2 \pi k l}{n}\right)^{2 m}}{\left(2 m\right)!}\right)
\nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{ n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0} \left(\sum^\infty_{m = 0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^m \left(2 \pi k l\right)^{2 m}}{n^{2 m}\left(2 m\right)!}\right)
\end{align}

Here, $1\le k \le \frac{n-2}{2}$.

I would like to compute the upper bound for this product as tight as possible.

**My attempt 1:**

Let $k = 1$:

$$
\frac{1}{ n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0} \left(\sum^\infty_{m = 0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^m \left(2 \pi k l\right)^{2 m}}{n^{2 m}\left(2 m\right)!}\right) = \frac{1}{ n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0} \left(\sum^\infty_{m = 0}\frac{\left(-1\right)^m \left(2 \pi  l\right)^{2 m}}{n^{2 m}\left(2 m\right)!}\right)  
$$

I do not know where to go from here.

**My attempt 2:**

\begin{align}
\langle \chi_{\sigma_k}, \chi_{\mathbf{ 1}_{D_n}} \rangle_{D_n} &= \frac{1}{2 n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0} 2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k l}{n}\right)
\nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{ n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0}  \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k l}{n}\right)
\nonumber\\
&= \frac{1}{n} \left(\cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k \cdot 0}{n}\right) + \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k \cdot 1}{n}\right) + \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k \cdot 2}{n}\right) + \ldots + \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k \cdot (n-1)}{n}\right)\right)
\end{align}

I do not know where to go from here either.

Comment: Isn't the sum always zero? I mean, if you call $\omega = e^{2 \pi i /n}$ then your sum should be something like $$\sum_l \mathrm{Re}(\omega^l) = \mathrm{Re} \left( \sum_l \omega^l \right) = \mathrm{Re} (0)=0$$ (I leave to you the details: the idea is that the sum of the roots of unity is $0$).

Comment: @Crostul, are you talking about the sum $ \frac{1}{2 n} \sum^{n-1}_{l = 0} 2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k l}{n}\right)$ ?

Comment: @Crostul, are you suggesting that $2 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi k l}{n}\right)$ is a root of unity?

Comment: @Crostul, I have found the following formula in http://evergreen.loyola.edu/mpknapp/www/papers/knapp-sv.pdf . $$\begin{align}
\sum^n_{l=1} \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi l}{n}\right) = 0
\end{align}$$

Comment: @Crostul, I have a multiplicative factor of $k$ inside the angle.

Comment: I'm definitely sure that your sum is always zero. The factor $k$ is irrelevant. I'm not going to write a proof, though; these things are standard algebra on complex numbers, much more basic than group representations.